# Convert tex file from latex to a word processing file (.doc, .rtf, or .ps)

Tags: ieeetran, msword, latex-to-word

Is it possible to convert an article in {IEEEtran} journal from latex into a word processing file doc., or others. How to add bibtex file and figure files. There are some examples available on some webpages, but they don't work on files. 
Here is some of code from my file:
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

All figures are filed in different place and figure code is 
\begin{figure*}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.65\textwidth]{./Figures/1.pdf}

reference style is 
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography {ref}

I want to convert the written article in IEEEtran latex into a word processing file.